# Make HTML custom field sortable in django-admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a very simple model that just consists of a name and serial number. I can use that serial number to ask for a status on an API and I want to display the result as icon/HTML:

```
class ProductAdminForm(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ["get_status", "name",]

    def get_status(self, obj):
        status = get_status_from_API(obj)["status"]
        style = """style="height: 10px; width: 10px; border-radius: 50%; COLOR display: inline-block;" """
    
        if status == 2:
            new_style = style.replace("COLOR", "background-color: green;")
        elif status == 1:
            new_style = style.replace("COLOR", "background-color: red;")
        else:
            new_style = style.replace("COLOR", "background-color: grey;")
        return mark_safe(f"""<span class="dot" {new_style}></span>""")
```

How can I make the  `get_status` column sortable?

Answer (score 1):

You can only sort on properties in the database.

> Usually, elements of list_display that aren’t actual database fields can’t be used in sorting (because Django does all the sorting at the database level).

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display

This means you cannot sort on the status of the object in the API. However you can sort on some other property, like the serial number, by setting `admin_order_field`.

If you really want to sort on the status you'll need to somehow store this status in the database.

One solution would be to periodically call a management command that fetches the status of all objects and stores the result in the database.

This makes it possible to sort (and filter) objects on their status.

Storing the API results in the database also has the upside of not needing to do any API calls when viewing the objects in the admin. This is particularly useful the when the API happens to be down/slow. The obvious downside being that results might be slightly outdated, depending on the frequency the update command is called.